How can an Inhomogeneous Poisson Process as a model for probability have a jump size of 1?
I have the probability of an event, happening at time $t$, $\operatorname{v}\left(t\right)$ being modelled by the following equation:
$$
\tau\,
\frac{{\rm d}\operatorname{v}\left(t\right)}{{\rm d}t}
= -\operatorname{v}\left(t\right) +
\tau a\sum_{k}\delta\left(t - t_{k}\right)
$$
where $t_{k}$ are random points drawn from a homogenous Poisson process, $a$ is a jump size and $\tau$ is a decay.
My understanding is the following:

If the Poisson process $t_{k}$ generates no points, then $\operatorname{v}\left(t\right)$ decays linearly by $\tau$.
But if Poisson process generates a point at $t$, then $\operatorname{v}\left(t\right)$ gets a 'jump'.
However the paper I'm reading does not bound the 'jump' to be  below $1$, and sets the jump $a = 1$.
But as $\operatorname{v}\left(t\right)$ is a probability, adding $+1$ will take
$\operatorname{v}\left(t\right) > 1$, which obviously cannot be because it is a probability.

What am I missing here ?.

I think you are right. Not you are missing something. That's the authors of that paper.
